# Make sure my bean gets created before the sessionFactory

Tags: hibernate, grails, flyway

I am trying to define a bean that gets created and initialized before the Hibernate 4 `sessionFactory` by adding this bean to the `resources.groovy`

```
beans = {

    if (Environment.current == PRODUCTION) {
        flyway(Flyway) { bean ->
            bean.initMethod = 'migrate'
            dataSource = ref('dataSource')
            locations = 'migration/db/mysql'
            initOnMigrate = true
        }
    }
}
```

No I would like to make sure that the `initMethod` is called before the creation of the `sessionFactory` without creating a separate Grails plugin.

Is there a way to do this or is it way too late when the `resources.groovy` is executed? I would like to migrate data using the `dataSource` bean and `Flyway` but initialize the Flyway bean before the `sessionFactory` starts to `validate` the database schema.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some hours I have found the answer. In Burt Beckwiths Book [Programming Grails](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920024750.do) there is a chapter called `Bean Postprocessors` and this is how Spring (or Grails) allows you to modify existing bean definition before the `applicationContext` gets finalized.

```
 beans = {

     if (application.config.flyway.enabled) {

         flyway(Flyway) { bean ->
             bean.initMethod = 'migrate'
             dataSource = ref('dataSource')
             locations = application.config.flyway.locations
             initOnMigrate = application.config.flyway.initOnMigrate
         }

         def sessionFactoryBeanDef = getBeanDefinition('sessionFactory')
         if (sessionFactoryBeanDef) {
             // make it depend on my bean
             sessionFactoryBeanDef.dependsOn = ['flyway'] as String[]
         }
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure, but I think `IntializingBean` gets execute before spring beans are created which includes `sessionFactory`.

```
public class SomeService implements InitializingBean {

    public void afterPropertiesSet() throws Exception {

    //initialization logic goes here

     }      
}
```

I am not sure if you can access `datasource`, if you can't you create then create it manually and then use it.

Comment: afterPropertiesSet is called after the bean has been created. but I cannot control the order (--> before the `sessionFactory` bean)